# Can click on jquery draggable parent start drag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have markup like this

```
<div id="colorpicker-background">
  <div id="colorpicker-selector"></div>
</div>
```

With JS like this:

```
$('#colorpicker-selector').draggable({
  containment : $('#colorpicker-background'),
  handle      : $('#colorpicker-selector')
})
```

When the user `onmousedown` fires on `#colorpicker-background` I move `#colorpicker-selector` to where the mousedown is. The problem is, the user can't continue to drag even though the selector is now under the cursor.

I have tried triggering drag, dragstart, mousedown, mousedown.draggable on `#colorpicker-selector` based on all sorts of posts I've read and am having no luck.

Another user here has had the same problem, but it's from 6 months ago, with no answer, and different jQuery versions ( as there have been many updates since then ): [jquery start dragging object when clicked on the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672222/jquery-start-dragging-object-when-clicked-on-the-other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `mousedown` I bind the function `updateSelector`

```
updateSelector = function( e ) {

 // update position yada yada...

 $('#colorpicker-selector').trigger( e ); // make the dragging happen

}
```

Comment: Note that you may have to change the event's target/currentTarget in order to avoid an infinite loop while triggering mousedown on it again.