# How can you programatically trigger draggable in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui

Just calling .trigger("mousedown"); doesn't work.

```
scrollPane_Y.draggable({
    axis: "y",
    stop: function (event, ui) { 
        /*
        i get triggered when the containment is hit
        so if a user hits the containment and then
        goes in the other direction nothing happens.
        */
         scrollPane_Y.trigger("mousedown"); // doesnt work
         scrollPane_Y.mousedown(function (e) { // from third link. doesnt work
             scrollPane_Y.trigger(e);
         });
    },
    containment: [0, min_scrollPane_Y, 0, max_scrollPane_Y]
});
```

- [causes infinite loop](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/9e8e339648901899827a58e5bf919f7dda03b88e/tests/jquery.simulate.js)
- [never explained](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)
- [doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252213/how-to-trigger-draggable-behaviour-programmatically)

Comment: Could you be more clear? Do you want stop user action when dragging element hit containement?

Answer (score 0):

You could directly call its private methods with correct parameters.

```
scrollPane_Y.draggable({
    axis: "y",
    stop: function (event, ui) { 
        /*
        i get triggered when the containment is hit
        so if a user hits the containment and then
        goes in the other direction nothing happens.
        */

         // retrieve the instance and call its private method
         scrollPane_Y.data("ui-draggable")._mouseDown(event);
    },
    containment: [0, min_scrollPane_Y, 0, max_scrollPane_Y]
});
```