# jquery start dragging object when clicked on the other with gwtquery and drag and drop

Tags: gwt, draggable, gwtquery

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672222/jquery-start-dragging-object-when-clicked-on-the-other) the question is asked how to initiate an immediate drag operation when another object is clicked.  I have the same question but in the context of gwtquery and the draggable plugin.

In the reference post the new item to be dragged is moved to be under the click point and the original mouse down event is sent on to it.  Is it possible to do this in gwt?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like that :

```
$("#myDraggable").as(Draggable).draggable();
$("#myOtherDiv").mousedown(new Function(){
@Override
public boolean f(Event e) {
    //position your draggable first
    //...
    $("#myDraggable").trigger(e);
    return false;
}
});
```

But the method trigger(Event e) doesn't exist yet in GQuery. I open an issue for covering that : http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/issues/detail?id=139